# Android TV Emulator No Internet

Tags: android, emulation

No matter the configuration, if I create a TV emulator using the AVD, it has no internet access. There is no such issue if I create a common phone/tablet emulator. Any ideas why this is happening? I've checked some answers suggesting to run the cmd and enter 8.8.8.8 as dns there, but it wont help...

Comment: This is a bug that was filed on the AOSP issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196799

Answer (score 0):

To get internet access please update to new emulator image.

Ex. from lollipop image  to marshmallow image